# Rewrite for-loop vectorized using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
def obj(f, pis, rs):
    out = np.zeros(f.size)

    for pi, r in zip(pis, rs):
        out += r * pi / (1 + np.dot(r, f))

    return out

p = np.array([0.42, 0.08, 0.42, 0.08])
r = np.array([[-1.0, 7.0, -1.0, 0.4],
              [-1.0, 7.0, 0.5, -1.0],
              [0.2, -1.0, -1.0, 0.4],
              [0.2, -1.0, 0.5, -1.0]
              ])
f = np.array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])
```

I want to vectorize this function.
Why is the below implementation not giving the same output:

```
def obj_vec(f, pis, rs):
    out = rs * pis / (1 + np.dot(r, f))

    return np.sum(out, axis=1)
```

How should `obj_vec()` be defined?

Comment: `return np.sum((r.T * p / (1 + np.dot(r, f))).T, axis=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use matrix multiplication:

```
(r.T * p) @ (1 / (1 + r @ f))
array([-0.05947314,  0.72218094, -0.74877589,  0.17774817])
```

---

```
((r.T * p) / ( 1 +  r @ f).T).sum(1)
array([-0.05947314,  0.72218094, -0.74877589,  0.17774817])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension for that one :

```
sum([ rs * pi / (1 + np.dot(rs, f)) for pi, rs in zip(p,r)])
```

output:

```
array([-0.05947314,  0.72218094, -0.74877589,  0.17774817])
```

Comment: A list comprehension is a nice way of writing loop, but is still iterating at the python level.  `numpy` 'vectorization' moves those loops into compiled code by using numpy methods. `dot` has been generalized to work with higher dimensions (batches if you will) using `matmul/@` or `einsum`.